# Flex Compiler 4.0 25% more rapid than Flex 3 compiler

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

Its stated in adobe site that the Flash Builder 4 compiler is indeed 25% more performing than the previous Flex Builder 3 compiler.

How can I confirm that?

For example if I make a simple application on Fx3 and the same on Fx4, then how would I compare the compiler performance using my project?

Thx
FlexBoz

Comment: It will probably be hard to tell with a simple application. Most likely you wont see a performance difference until you have an application with modules, where the compiler needs to optimize what objects and components to compile into which SWF.

Comment: So It complies your swf in .75 instead of 1 second? I don't get why concern yourself of something that you couldn't change even if you wanted to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `benchmark` [compiler argument](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html) to output compile times and such.

I'm in agreement with SuperSaiyen that you'd likely need a project of significant size to see any differences.  My own experience in upgrading from Flex Builder 3 to Flash Builder 4 has been that, yeah, mxmlc is probably a little bit faster in FB4 but the best way to improve compile times is to optimize your project (e.g., move all embedded fonts to a library project and add them to your main project via SWCs).